# Dataframe load from python to snowflake via EC2

Tags: python, pandas, database-connection, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a python data frame which I need to load in snowflake tables. I was doing that via Jupyter notebook and I was able to load the data. However, when I ran the same code in EC2 I encountered segmentation fault error. I want to ask is it possible to load data from python dataframe to snowflake using other method like creating a temp CSV and load the same via python or changing it in pyarrow format and then load it in snowflake via python. Please note that I can't use S3 bucket.

Comment: I recommend you update your question with more details.  Error messages, sample code, etc.  There is clearly something different about your local machine and your EC2 instance, but without any details, it's impossible to point you in the right direction and debug your issue.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to paste the code as it is in virtual environment..I will try to post the code of local machine... meanwhile can you suggest other methods to load the data to snowflake

Comment: I think you need to figure out why write_pandas() isn't working on the EC2 instance, because it is running the same commands that you'd be trying to use in alternative solutions (PUT and COPY INTO).

Answer (score 0):

Your best method is using the `write_pandas()` function, which will create a temp file, `PUT` it to Snowflake internal stage, and then execute a `COPY INTO` command for you.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#label-python-connector-api-write-pandas

This is not the only way, though, and since your question doesn't specify which method you are using, I thought I'd start with the best way.  If this is the way you are already using, I'll update this answer.

Comment: I have used both write_pandas() and pd_writer using to_sql but I get error everytime I use them in EC2... However both were working in my local system...Please specify what other methods can be used to load the data...Thanks in advance

Comment: I used traceback to check the error in EC2 and found that I got below error: 255001: Binding data in type (method) is not supported....Could you please share what's wrong here as same data was loaded via local machine to snowflake but now I am getting this error.